# How to dynamically add FormControl to FormArray on button click in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

How can I add a `formcontrol(option)` dynamically in `formarray`? I want to dynamically add questions to a `formarray`. Upon clicking a button, it should update the display. I'm using angular 7.

### Component code

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.quizForm = this.fb.group({
    questions: this.fb.array([]),
    questions2: this.fb.array([]),
  });
}
    
//creating formcontrol
createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    ques: '',
  });
}
    
//pushing code
genField() {
  this.message = true;
  this.questions = this.quizForm.get('questions') as FormArray;
  this.questions.push(this.createItem());
}
```

### HTML Template

I want to add form control option dynamically on button click and form control should be inside the `formArrayName="questions"`.

```
<form [formGroup]="quizForm" class="adjust-form">
  <div formArrayName="questions" 
    *ngFor="let item of quizForm.get('questions').controls; let i = index;">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-6 mt-3 mb-3" [formGroupName]="i">
      <label>{{i +1}} - {{question}} </label>
      <i class="flaticon-delete"    
          (click)="quizForm.get('questions').controls.splice(i,1) "
          style="font-size: 9px;padding-left: 80px;">
      </i>
      <div class="row">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-10"
            [(ngModel)]="item.ques" formControlName="ques"
            placeholder="Enter your question" required>
        <button *ngIf="i == 0" (click)="genField()" type="button"
            class="btn btn-secondary btn-elevate btn-circle btn-icon ml-4">
            <i class="flaticon2-plus"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="item.touched && item.invalid" class="kt-font-danger text-left">
        <p>required</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please add your html file snipper aswell? since i cant see anythign wrong in the ts file and are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 52):

This example dynamically adds email fields to a reactive form. This would be used to enable users to add multiple email addresses (e.g. Home and Work).

This demo has the following dependencies: Angular 8, [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/categories), [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/)

### End Result ([**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-dynamic-add-control-so59033703?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts))

[image: Angular Form Demo - dynamically add form controls]

### Step 1: Define the form model

```js
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.emailForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    emails: this.formBuilder.array([this.createEmailFormGroup()])
  });
}
```

### Step 2: Define a method to dynamically construct new `FormGroup`

```js
private createEmailFormGroup(): FormGroup {
  return new FormGroup({
    'emailAddress': new FormControl('', Validators.email),
    'emailLabel': new FormControl('')
  })
}
```

### Step 3: Define a method to dynamically add new `FormGroup` to the `FormArray`

```js
public addEmailFormGroup() {
  const emails = this.emailForm.get('emails') as FormArray
  emails.push(this.createEmailFormGroup())
}
```

### Step 4 (Optional): Define method to delete `FormGroup`

```js
public removeOrClearEmail(i: number) {
  const emails = this.emailForm.get('emails') as FormArray
  if (emails.length > 1) {
    emails.removeAt(i)
  } else {
    emails.reset()
  }
}
```

### Step 5: Create the HTML form template

```html
<form [formGroup]="emailForm">
  <div formArrayName="emails">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let email of emailForm.get('emails').controls; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i">
```

Note that within the `formArrayName` element, the dynamic email `FormGroups` are named based on the array index.

### Final Form

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    Angular Form Demo - Dynamically add form controls
</mat-toolbar>

<form class="basic-container" [formGroup]="emailForm">
  <div formArrayName="emails">
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let email of emailForm.get('emails').controls; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i">

      <div class="col-1">
        <mat-icon class="mt-3">email</mat-icon>
      </div>

      <mat-form-field class="col-4">
        <input matInput formControlName="emailAddress" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="email">
        <mat-error *ngFor="let validation of validationMsgs.emailAddress">
          <div *ngIf="email.get('emailAddress').hasError(validation.type)">
            {{validation.message}}
          </div>
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="col-4">
        <mat-label>Label</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="emailLabel">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let label of emailLabels" [value]="label">
            {{label}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <div class="col-3">
        <button class="float-left" mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Remove/clear"
            (click)="removeOrClearEmail(i)" matTooltip="Remove">
          <mat-icon>highlight_off</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button class="float-left" mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Add"
            (click)="addEmailFormGroup()" matTooltip="Add">
          <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

### Final Component

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public emailForm: FormGroup;
  public emailLabels = ['Home', 'Work', 'Other'];
  public validationMsgs = {
    'emailAddress': [{ type: 'email', message: 'Enter a valid email' }]
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.emailForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      emails: this.formBuilder.array([this.createEmailFormGroup()])
    });
  }

  public addEmailFormGroup() {
    const emails = this.emailForm.get('emails') as FormArray
    emails.push(this.createEmailFormGroup())
  }

  public removeOrClearEmail(i: number) {
    const emails = this.emailForm.get('emails') as FormArray
    if (emails.length > 1) {
      emails.removeAt(i)
    } else {
      emails.reset()
    }
  }

  private createEmailFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      'emailAddress': new FormControl('', Validators.email),
      'emailLabel': new FormControl('')
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to make FormArray Push to something like unshift of javascript method ?

Comment: I created the POC using this solution, then I implemented similar functionality in my project. thanks  @Christopher

Comment: If you're getting this error: "Cannot find control with name: '0'" — 
it means you're missing the `formArrayName` directive ;)

Comment: After push FormGroup to FormArray in step-3, I saw all of old items had been changed to new one!