# Dynamically add control to form in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I've created this form here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay58g9

I'm getting an error when selecting the option from select menu that I'm not able to solve.

Also, I want the output like this:

```
When 'form data' selected in dropdown:
[
  data_type: 'form_data',
  form_data: {
    firstname: "saurabh",
    lastname: "Sharma"
  }
]

When 'form data' selected in dropdown:
[
  data_type: 'raw_data',
  raw_data: {
    email: "saurabh@gmail.com",
    contactno: "9999999999"
  }
]
```

COuld you please look into it and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: See [Angular: How to dynamically add FormControl to FormArray on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59033703/1164465)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted your example a bit: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avcytw

Your dynamically added formControls are within formGroups. 
Therefore the most important thing is to add `formGroupName` to the inputs parent elements.

```
<div *ngIf="this.form.get('form_data')" formGroupName="form_data">
        <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" placeholder="firstname">
        <input type="text" formControlName="lastname"  placeholder="lastname">
    </div>
```

Also the initial form needed to be adjusted:

```
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      data_type: ["", Validators.required],
      // form_data: new FormControl(),
      // raw_data: new FormControl()   
    });
```

`form_data: new FormControl()` and `raw_data: new FormControl()` caused the ngIfs to render before you add the corresponding form controls dynamically. Thats why there were errors indicating the formControls can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Reactive Forms with Angular, my suggestion is to look into using a FormArray.

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: [''],
  formData: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.control('')
  ])
});
```

Angular Documentation: 
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays