# use splice in Angular Reactive Form to add new controls at given index position

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular. I am currently working on Angular Form Builder. I have employee List(name and salary) in todo.service and display these list in  todo-list.html using form-builder. I would like, when click the change  button, new employee list (name: mayank and salary: 70000) is added below this index position. For this we used splice() method. At the first time project work right. but the second, third and so on times target employee list (name: mayank and salary: 70000) is not added the right position. e.g. When I click Vivek1 button, mayank is added below Vivek1. After that when I click Vivek4 button, mayank is not added below Vivek4.
https://github.com/777Vikki/Add-list-in-array-using-splice

Comment: Your logic is wrong, explain little bit more, what your trying to do?

Comment: I updated the project.

Comment: You could try using `FormArray` and its `insert` method. See [dyamic form example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118097/1164465)