# Angular material How to create dynamically add multiple autocomplete in same form

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

In my Angular material project. On one reactive form I need to dynamically add multiple autocomplete fields. All autocomplete fields have a different array of options prefetched from a service onInit.

[Current static exmaple on StackBlitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afwnsu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts)

My question is: how can What changes should I make to 
1. make sure not to repeat the code in template and ts file, as you can see all the filter* observables and reparative template code is quickly getting out of hand.
2. dynamically add more fields based on data from the backend. Backend data will have information about the list of options, labels, placeholders, control name etc.

Comment: This answer shows how to dynamically add Angular Material controls: [**Angular: How to dynamically add FormControl**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118097/1164465). Rather than waiting for user events, the dynamic components could be render as soon as data is fetched from the server.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I understand the part on how to add a formcontrol to formGroup in the component file. The problem I am facing is with the autocomplete field. Each autocomplete field requires "filtered Observable array" of values. Also each autocomplete field requires template variable. My question is more of how to have array of autocomplete fields on a form?

Answer (score 1):

I finally ended up writing my own FormField by implementing `MatFormFieldControl` having Typeahed support. Only thing that is limiting is right now the typeahead accepts prefetched values. In next iteration I'd love to provide typeahead with webservice support.